# In c++, how can I pass all of current function's arguments to another function?

Tags: c++

Is there an expression in c++ that allows me to pass all of the current function's arguments, in order, to another function? See the example below.

```
int bar(int a, char* b, double c)
{

}

int foo(int a, char* b, double c)
{
    bar({what goes here?});    // Equivalent to bar(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: `bar(a, b, c)`?

Comment: `bar(a, b, c);` will pass those three arguments. Under some circumstances, you might want to define the parameters as rvalue references, and use `std::forward` when calling the function (but for the types you're passing here, that probably won't make any difference).

Comment: There are template-oriented ways for passing argument lists, but really nothing for a simple case like yours where simply being less lazy is the best solution.

Comment: You could group all 3 variables in a struct and pass one parameter to the function, which would be a struct pointer or reference. That way, you only have to deal with one parameter instead of 3. However, depending on your program, that may not be meaningful, especially if you want to pass the variables by value instead of by pointer/reference.

Comment: @paddy Well maybe someone just asks upon a simple example to find a universal solution for a more complex problem based upon this principle?

Answer (score 0):

I read a book on clean code awhile ago that advocated for a max of 2 function arguments. 3 was only for extenuating circumstances and 4 was a heinous crime.

If you're going to be passing `a`, `b` and `c` around together often, clearly they mean something together. So in a case like this, the book would suggest making a struct to hold that information:

```
struct Abc {
    int a;
    char *b;
    double c;
};

int bar(Abc abc)
{

}

int foo(Abc abc)
{
    bar(abc);
}
```

This way you don't punish yourself for longer, more descriptive names, and you can add another informative name for what all three of those values mean together.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in having many arguments if they don't represent a single abstraction. Here we cannot say anything about the arguments' meaning so it's just speculation. This also doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Sopel note that I didn't say I *agree* with the practice. However, in this case, if you're passing the same arguments around multiple times (so often that you need to ask a SO question about it), I think it's safe to assume there's some way to abstract those into a struct. If nothing else, they could be abstracted as `struct foo_bar_args`.

Comment: "However, in this case, if you're passing the same arguments around multiple times (so often that you need to ask a SO question about it), I think it's safe to assume there's some way to abstract those into a struct. " fair enough

Comment: While there's a lot of wisdom and tech to take from Uncle Bob's Clean Code book, this answer doesn't answer the question `how can I pass all of current function's arguments to another function?`.

Comment: @Sopel `There is nothing wrong in having many arguments if they don't represent a single abstraction` There is. It's hard to read, hard to use, it looks ugly and clutters the code: it either shifts to the right or you have to make that function multiline, which looks very ugly. Here Uncle Bob makes a case why you shouldn't pass many arguments to a function: https://youtu.be/SVRiktFlWxI?t=5824 . Once you have a function that can take a lot of arguments, it's probably better to create a separate class for it, create that object and call that function on that object.

Comment: @scohe001 With the Abc struct, this isn't what Uncle Bob meant. He meant to refactor the function together with the arguments into its' own object, so you can then just call `abc.bar()`, not `bar(abc)`.